# Magento 2 : Get Customer Collection with it's Attribute

Tags: magento2, customer, collection

I've managed to get customer collection using class **`\Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\CollectionFactory`**

but it returns me default details not with **`Created Customer Attributes`**.

> **Any idea how to get Customer Collection with it's Attributes ?**

Comment: See the answer here.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/242368/magento-2-how-to-get-customer-collection-filter-by-full-name-like-admin-grid

Answer (score 3):

**Get Customer Attribute values by Group and Customer Id**

Create Helper file **Data.php**

**Path:** `{VendorName}/{ModuleName}/Helper/Data.php`

```
<?php

namespace {VendorName}\{ModuleName}\Helper;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface
    ) {
        $this->customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getCustomerDataObject($customerId) {
        $customer = $this->customerRepositoryInterface->getById($customerId);
        return $customerAttributeData = $customer->__toArray();
    }
}

?>
```

Create Block file **index.php**

**Path:** `{VendorName}/{ModuleName}/Block/Index/index.php`

```
<?php
namespace {VendorName}\{ModuleName}\Block\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\CollectionFactory $customerFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getCustomer($customergroupId)
    {
        $customerCollection = $this->customerFactory->create();
        $customerCollection->addFieldToFilter('group_id',$customergroupId);
        return $customerCollection;
    }
}

?>
```

Create phtml file **index.phtml**

**Path:** `{VendorName}/{ModuleName}/view/frontend/templates/index.phtml`

```
<?php

    $customerHelper = $this->helper(\{VendorName}\{ModuleName}\Helper\Data::class);

    $groupId = 4;
    $customerCollection = $block->getCustomer($groupId);

    foreach ($customerCollection as $customer) {

        $customerId = $customer->getId();
        $customerAttributeData = $customerHelper->getCustomerDataObject($customerId);
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($customerAttributeData); //Get All Attribute Values of Customer

        echo $customer->getFirstname().' '.$customer->getLastname();

        if (isset($customerAttributeData['custom_attributes']['{attribute_code}'])) {
        $attributeCode = $customerAttributeData['custom_attributes']['{attribute_code}']['value'];
            if (!empty($attributeCode)) {
                echo '<div class="field customer-sale-leader">';
                echo $attributeCode;
                echo '</div>';
            }
        }

    }
?>
```

Follow above steps It's work for you.

Thanks!