# How to filter customer collection with its attribute?

Tags: customer, collection, magento2.3

**I've bunch of customer attributes, So how can I filter customer collection with its custom attribute ?**

Comment: See the answer here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/242368/magento-2-how-to-get-customer-collection-filter-by-full-name-like-admin-grid

Answer (score 0):

Use `addFieldToFilter()` method.

Example

```
$replydb = $objectManager->get('\Vendor\Module\Model\Yourmodel')->getCollection();
$replydb->addFieldToFilter('status', 'Approved');
$replycoll = $replydb->getData();
```